# Create executable war with embedded tomcat 9 with gradle

Tags: tomcat, gradle

I have built a web application using spring and gradle which I am running on Tomcat, however I want to create a war file which will initialize the web application and tomcat all in one using an embedded tomcat 9. What is the best to create this? As I am struggling to correctly achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I assume its spring boot application.
To get executable jar file execude `bootJar` task:

```
gradle bootJar
```

or run directly war file

```
java -jar app.war
```

Comment: But how can I configure the embed tomcat?

Comment: what you mean `configure`? what you need to configure?

Comment: I had external tomcat configured for the project not embedded.